# Is it possible to see when and how a file was deleted?

Tags: windows-7, file-management

An application I'm working has unexpectedly deleted some data files from a folder.

Is it possible in windows 7 to pull up some kind of log for that folder, to see when the files were deleted, and what command deleted them?

Answer (score 4):

You need to configure few settings in Local Group Policy and on the particular folder settings. Please follow the below steps to track the Deleted files. It can bring you the information such as Timestamp when the file is deleted and user account who deleted the file.

Run > gpedit.msc > Computer Configuration --> Windows Settings --> Security Settings --> Local Policies --> Audit Policy --> Audit object Access > enable 'Success' audit. 
Now open a command prompt and run "gpupdate /force" command in order take the group policy settings effect.

Once Local GPO is in place, go to the folder you want to monitor, right click and go to properties:
Click the security tab > Advanced > Auditing Tab > Edit > Add > then add the group that has access to that folder > Select "Delete Folders and Subfolder files" and "Delete", and click OK --> Select Replace all existing inheritable audit entries, to appply the audit on "All sub folders and files" and click OK

Now, delete some test file and filter the Event ID 4660 and Event ID 4663 with keyword 'DELETE' will let you know more details.

Hope this helps.